# how come displayName not valid property when using TransitiveMemberOf in Graph call?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to make a small azure function that returns the display name of the users groups they are member of.

this is the snippet of code that works fine:

```
var messagePage = await graphClient.Me
               .TransitiveMemberOf
               .Request()
               .GetAsync();
```

However if I want to return only the displayName property using this code:

```
var messagePage = await graphClient.Me
               .TransitiveMemberOf
               .Request()
               .Select(g => new
               {
                   g.displayName
               })
               .GetAsync();
```

It tells me displayName is not a valid property but it clearly is if I look at the response from the first query without the filter it returns this property:

```
 "createdDateTime": "2022-04-13T01:46:09+00:00",
        "description": "brand-xxx",
        "displayName": "brand-xxx",
```

So the property is there why can I not filter it out ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to specify only property name in `Select` method where the properties you want to return are specified as string.

```
var messagePage = await client.Me.TransitiveMemberOf
    .Request()
    .Select("displayName") // .Select("id,displayName,...")
    .GetAsync();
```

You are using `Select` method with expression

```
Select(Expression<Func<DirectoryObject, object>> selectExpression);
```

where `DirectoryObject` is a base class for `Group`, so you can try to cast it

```
var messagePage = await client.Me
           .TransitiveMemberOf
           .Request()
           .Select(g => new
           {
               ((Group)g).DisplayName
           })
           .GetAsync();
```

But the first option seems to me better and easy to use.